# error(existence_error(procedure,(:-)/1),top_level/0) error prolog

Tags: prolog

```
% FACTS. 
mammal(kitty).
mammal(ratatat).
mammal(fido).
claws(kitty).
tail(ratatat).
bestfriend(fido).
feathers(tweety).

% 9 RULES. 
% If X is a mammal then X has fur. 
fur(X) :- mammal(X).
% If X has fur and X has a tail then X is a rat. 
rat(X) :- fur(X),tail(X).
% If X has claws and X has fur then X is a cat.
cat(X) :- claws(X),fur(X).
% If X is a cat then X meows.
meows(X) :- cat(X).
% If X has feathers then X is a bird.
bird(X) :- feathers(X).
% If X is a bestfriend and X has fur then X is a dog.
dog(X) :- bestfriend(X),fur(X).
% If X is a dog and Y meows then X likes Y.
likes(X,Y) :- dog(X),meows(Y).
% If X is a cat and Y is a bird then X likes Y.
likes(X,Y) :- cat(X),bird(Y).
% If X is a cat and Y is a rat then X likes Y.
likes(X,Y) :- cat(X),rat(Y).

writeln(T) :- write(T), nl.

% QUERY. Uncomment after you have written all predicates.
q1 :- findall(X, (likes(X,Y), format('~n~w ~w',[X,Y])),_).
end :- writeln('#'), halt.
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this error is happening when I attempt to run.

#### Expected result

```
?- likes(X,Y).
X = fido,
Y = kitty ;
X = kitty,
Y = tweety ;
X = kitty,
Y = ratatat ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: also if someone can explain how to use the Querys at the bottom the q1 and end  ones would be very helpful thanks!

Comment: Code looks fine. just type `q1.` and enter.

Comment: I ran this on `swipl` and it generates the expected result. Perhaps there is an issue with spaces on your side?

Comment: thanks guys i thought i was doing something wrong is there any way i can type -: likes(X,Y). and it give the given out put with out using the q1 query ?

Comment: @chriskelly yes. Your code should work as-is with the `likes(X, Y).` query. Your error message says it can't find `:-`. DO NOT type the `:-`. That's the Prolog prompt!

Comment: lurker has your answer.  Typing the `:-` was what messed you up.